Supabase Prisma Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `aws-0-ap-southeast-1.pooler.supabase.com`:`5432`
I am trying to build a next.js project with Supabase and Prisma.
This is part of my schema.prisma file:
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["multiSchema"]
}

datasource db {
  provider  = "postgresql"
  url       = env("DATABASE_URL")
  directUrl = env("DIRECT_URL")
  schemas   = ["public", "auth"]
}

The error occurs when I run npx prisma db push command in my terminal. I get this error:
Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `aws-0-ap-southeast-1.pooler.supabase.com`:`5432`
Please make sure your database server is running at `aws-0-ap-southeast-1.pooler.supabase.com`:`5432`.

My DATABASE_URL and DIRECT_URL are as per this document:
https://supabase.com/partners/integrations/prisma

Verify that you can connect to the postgres instance with another tool, psql.  Then check that your credentials are configured

For whatever reason, it worked for me after updating prisma.
Run the following to update:
 npm i --save-dev prisma@latest 
 npm i @prisma/client@latest

